# Add dataframe column that will represent a 'resetting index'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what I'm looking for:

Original DF:

```
    Col1   
0   Dave
1   Dave
2   Mike
3   Mike
4   Mike
5   Jeff
```

Desired DF:

```
    Col1   Col2
0   Dave     1
1   Dave     2
2   Mike     1
3   Mike     2
4   Mike     3
5   Jeff     1
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can use `groupby` with `cumcount`

Comment: `df['Col2'] = df.groupby('Col1').cumcount()+1` would do